# Dataframe creation from a multiindex

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index

I have a pandas series values, stored in variable s, which was formed using Multi Indexing.
Code-

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(50), index=idx)
```

Here is how s looks like-

[image]

What is the best way to create a dataframe of this?

Comment: [s.to_frame()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) or [s.reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) depending on what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of series you can use dataframe and input your own multi index list.

```py
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(50), index=idx)
```